# What is the recommended way of passing keyboad events to QProcess transparently?

Tags: c++, qt, qprocess

I have a GUI application, which creates a `QProcess` inside, catches its output and shows it on a form. I need to somehow catch key events from the form to pass them to `QProcess` (to make it fell as close as possible to real terminal window).

So, I suppose, I should process `keyReleaseEvent()` and somehow transform either `event.text()` (which is `QString`) or `event.key()` (which is `int`) to argument, suitable for `process.write()` (which takes `char*` or `QByteArray`). Is there some recommended way to do such a conversion (taking into account localization issues, ctrl/alt/shift modifiers and so on)? I do not really want to construct some sort of mapping from `key()` return values to `char*` strings; and `text()` drops modifiers.

Moreover, if I start process with command `bash -c sudo something` in QProcess, it exits instantly, complaining that "no tty present and no askpass program specified", so I may be doing something completely wrong...

Comment: Just commenting since this doesn't answer the main issue. To deal with the "no tty..." issue you can ensure you set the SUDO_ASKPASS environment variable with QProcess::setEnvironment (http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qprocess.html#setEnvironment). It must be set to the path of a program to run which takes argument (the prompt) and writes the password to standard output.

Comment: I would prefer not to set some esoteric variables for each over-paranoidal program... I hope there is a general way to make my QProcess behave exactly like the terminal application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is more than just deciding what to write to the process.

You can't emulate a terminal just by reading/writing stdout/stdin of a process, it's more complicated than that.  Think about the program `less`, or any pager, for example.  How does it know how many lines to print at a time?  It needs information about the terminal which isn't represented through stdin/stdout/stderr.

Emulating a terminal is beyond the scope of QProcess.  If you're really sure you need to do this then use some existing Qt-based terminal emulator as a starting point (e.g. Konsole).

Comment: Yes, Konsole seems to do exactly what I want to... I will probably have to cut some parts from it )